# Is there any AirPort product that supports to receive audio streaming and share a hard drive on USB?

Tags: airport

My impression is that I need both an Airport Express for sound, and an AirPort Extreme for sharing the hard drive.

Is this true, or there are alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your impression is correct. AirPort Express's USB port [does not support hard drives](http://www.apple.com/airportexpress/specs.html), and AirPort Extreme doesn't have an audio output jack:

[image]

Sucks, don't it?